# Use Bezier Path as Clipping Mask

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, clipping

I am wondering if it is possible to clip a view to a Bezier Path. What I mean is that I want to be able to see the view only in the region within the closed Bezier Path. The reason for this is that I have the outline of an irregular shape, and I want to fill in the shape gradually with a solid color from top to bottom. If I could make it so that a certain view is only visible within the path then I could simply create a UIView of the color I want and then change the y coordinate of its frame as I please, effectively filling in the shape. If anyone has any better ideas for how to implement this that would be greatly appreciated. For the record the filling of the shape will match the y value of the users finger, so it can't be a continuous animation. Thanks.

Update (a very long time later):

I tried your answer, Rob, and it works great except for one thing. My intention was to move the view being masked while the mask remains in the same place on screen. This is so that I can give the impression of the mask being "filled up" by the view. The problem is that with the code I have written based on your answer, when I move the view the mask moves with it. I understand that that is to be expected because all I did was add it as the mask of the view so it stands to reason that it will move if the thing it's tied to moves. I tried adding the mask as a sublayer of the superview so that it stays put, but that had very weird results. Here is my code:

```
self.test = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
self.test.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

[self.view addSubview:self.test];

UIBezierPath *myClippingPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[myClippingPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
[myClippingPath addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(200, 200) controlPoint1:CGPointMake(self.screenWidth, 0) controlPoint2:CGPointMake(self.screenWidth, 50)];
[myClippingPath closePath];


CAShapeLayer *mask = [CAShapeLayer layer];
mask.path = myClippingPath.CGPath;

self.test.layer.mask = mask;

CGRect firstFrame = self.test.frame;
firstFrame.origin.x += 100;
[UIView animateWithDuration:3 animations:^{
    self.test.frame = firstFrame;
}];
```

Thanks for the help already.

Comment: try masking the superview of `self.test` instead. The superlayer's mask will affect sublayers and will only move with the superlayer.

Comment: Instead of moving a view. I would suggest that you calculate a rect using the `Y` coord from User's finger. Then call `setNeedsDisplay` on the `View`. Inside the View's `drawRect` fill up the calculated rectangle. And during this whole process just let the above mentioned `CAShapeLayer` mask be there :) :) (though I will suggest you use Clipping of paths, for a better learning experience :)). cheers

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can do this easily by setting your view's layer mask to a `CAShapeLayer`.

```
UIBezierPath *myClippingPath = ...

CAShapeLayer *mask = [CAShapeLayer layer];
mask.path = myClippingPath.CGPath;

myView.layer.mask = mask;
```

You will need to add the `QuartzCore` framework to your target if you haven't already.

---

In Swift ...

```
let yourCarefullyDrawnPath = UIBezierPath( .. blah blah
let maskForYourPath = CAShapeLayer()
maskForYourPath.path = carefullyRoundedBox.CGPath
layer.mask = maskForYourPath
```

Comment: Help needed @robmayoff

Comment: Note that conveniently this **DOES clip all subviews**. Totally awesome.  It's interesting that (if I'm not mistaken) the "clip subviews" parameter then DOES NOT "work" with this: i.e., if you do what Rob explains here, it **will** clip subviews like this, regardless, of whether you have "clip subviews" on or off!

Answer (score 3):

Just an example of Rob's solution, there's a `UIWebView` sitting as a **subview** of a `UIView` called `smoothView`. `smoothView` uses `bezierPathWithRoundedRect` to make a rounded gray background (notice on right). That works fine.

But if `smoothView` has only normal clip-subviews, you get this:

[image]

If you do what Rob says, you get the rounded corners in `smoothView` **and all subviews** ...

[image]

Great stuff.