# UITableViewCell's subviews can't be round

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, layer

I want to create a tableview that has some round subview as UIView. I set the UIView's layer.cornerRadius and clipsToBounds. But some views are not round. Who can help me to solve this problem or give me some advice?

My code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString * settCellID = @"settingCellID";
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:settCellID];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:settCellID];

        UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 10, 20, 20)];
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
        view.clipsToBounds = 1;
        view.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
        view.layer.shouldRasterize = 1;
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:view];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Is this occurring on device or on the simulator?

Comment: what is the value you return as row height. is that bigger than the height of this rounded view.

Comment: is this occurring in simulator? then there is a possibility of simulator glitches.set the simulator scale to 100% (In menu : Window -> Scale -> 100%) and then check.

Comment: This occurring on simulator and the device.My iphone6s also have this problem. @beyowulf

Comment: Yes, the row heigh is 43.0f @ Anuradh S

Comment: Yes, my result image is the simulator window is 100%. and the iphone also have this problem.@Jeyamahesan Chandrakanthan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Will Try it With Create a Custom Cell Class, and create your view not a programmatically its create using storyboard. and set property of view in custom cell class. then implement above code but a little changes here i have mention it.

```
static NSString * settCellID = @"settingCellID";
'CustomClassName' * cell = (CustomClassName*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:settCellID];
cell.viewPropertyName.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
cell.viewPropertyName.clipsToBounds = YES;
cell.viewPropertyName.maskToBounds =YES;
cell.viewPropertyName.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I solve the problem used your suggest. I don't know what the  difference about our way to create a round view. The round view which used your way created more like a clrcle. Please tell me if you know it.

Answer (score 0):

Inside this clipsToBound is Bool so you should Give YES or NO and Try To use maskToBound = YES for Corner Radius If you want to merge the below view Than use clipsToBound accordingly And I don't think that rasterizationScale and shouldRasterize is useful here. I hope This Will Help you.

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString * settCellID = @"settingCellID";
UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:settCellID];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:settCellID];

    UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 10, 20, 20)];
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    view.clipsToBounds = YES;
    view.maskToBounds =YES;
    view.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    view.layer.shouldRasterize = 1;
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:view];
}
return cell;
}
```

And If You Want To UITableViewCell rounded corners and clip subviews than Follow This [Link Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331632/uitableviewcell-rounded-corners-and-clip-subviews)

Comment: The rasterizationScale and shouldRasterize is for "Off-Screen Rendering",but it has no effect on the round view. and the "view.clipsToBounds = YES" is eque to "view.layer.masksToBounds = 1". I already used the CGContextRef and UIBezierPath to create a round view on the UITableViewCell, but they can't create a real round view.

Comment: Then Make Custom Cell in Storyboard and set user define Run Time Attributes I am Sure That will Help You for using user define run time attribute prefer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301256/is-it-possible-to-set-uiview-border-properties-from-interface-builder

Comment: Thanks for your help. I already solve this problem used the Rock's way. Only used the custom round view could solve this problem. But i don't know what the difference about them.@Kartik Singh Bhadoriya

Comment: 1 up vote by me Because you solved your problem great. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The rasterizationScale and shouldRasterize is for "Off-Screen Rendering",but it has no effect on the round view. and the "view.clipsToBounds = YES" is eque to "view.layer.masksToBounds = 1". I already used the CGContextRef and UIBezierPath to create a round view on the UITableViewCell, but they can't create a real round view.